# Can I custom panel admin when app is already created?

Tags: strapi

I have a question

Can I custom panel admin when app is already created?

In the documentation https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/advanced/customize-admin.html#customization is written a project should be created in the dev mode with --dev flag, but I worked since 2 weeks on the project which I created  without this flag, but now I want to add to admin panel one simple component and rebuild panel admin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible but the process is not easy.

What I would suggest is to create a dev app that has the same apis as your prod one. To do so you can follow step 1 and 2 from this [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1943#issuecomment-430533710).
Instead of recreating your apis just copy the api folder from your prod app into the dev one (if you made relations with the user model copy the `./plugins/users-permissions/models/User.settings.json` file into the dev app, don't forget to restart your server).

Once you completed your modifications. Run `npm run setup --plugins` at the root of your dev application to make sure the build completes flawlessly.

At this point, you can reinstall Strapi globally `npm install strapi@alpha -g`.
Here you have two options, either copy your modifications into your prod application and run `npm run setup --plugins` at the root of the app or copy the generated build folder from the dev application into the other one.

Hope this helps.